# Close box after clicking same item which opens the box

Tags: jquery

When I click an item, a box appears. I know how to do with clicking different item but, if possible, when I click the **same** item again it should close.

How can I achieve?

Thanks

**THIS JUST OPENS:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#default_search').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#search').fadeIn(500);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**THIS OPENS and CLOSES IMMEDIATELY which is WRONG:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#default_search').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#search').fadeIn(500);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('#default_search').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#search').fadeOut(500);
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use 2 click events for the same element. Use [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/)

```
$('#default_search').click(function(event)
{
    $('#search').fadeToggle(500);
});
```

Comment: @MadMax - yes it is :) glad to help.